Flutter Deeplink works well on Android, but returns "faild to handler route information in flutter" after opening the app on an iOS device
I used go_router to set up deep links.
Here are the contents of my apple-app-site-association file
{
"applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
        {
            "appIDs": [
                "myTeamID.com.example.app"
            ],
            "paths": [
                "*"
            ],
            "components": [
                {
                    "/": "/*"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
"webcredentials": {
    "apps": [
        "myTeamID.com.example.app"
    ]
}
} 

I've activated FlutterDeepLinkingEnabled
I followed the instructions in the flutter guide on configuring deeplinks on https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/set-up-universal-links
before I had associated my domain without www like this applinks:example.com as indicated in the deeplinks configuration guide on the flutter site, with this the deeplinks didn't even open the application, then I read that I had to add another domain with www, after adding the application started to open when I clicked on a deeplink but returning the error "failed to handler route information in flutter" just after opening.
At the moment the deep links open the application without going to any page and on the emulator the deep link opens the application and the site at the same time, the application first and then the site.
Please help me solve this problem

I had this issue when I forgot to host the apple-app-site-association.json file to the Apple bots. enter link description here
Apple needs to reach this file in a public host to setup your universal links. If it is not setup yet, it'll wont work.
It means that this file you created be accessible for everyone in a public address. Have you done that?

Yes, I deployed the file according to Apple's request and even checked with the command: curl -v link , you can use this command to check the hosting of my configuration file.

might related to this.
https://github.com/Milad-Akarie/auto_route_library/issues/2055
I updated this key to false to avoid that error
ios/Runner/Info.plist
<key>FlutterDeepLinkingEnabled</key>
<false/>

